# How to make responsive background image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

everyone.I want to make a full width background image as responsive.I am using bootstrap3.00 framework.as usually when some one use bootstrap framework it make a template as responsive but the background which i used that is situated outside of the bootstrap container.and when i look it for a small device the background image shows scroll bar.Now how can i fixed the problem??please the experts give me a suitable solution.

Comment: How do your html and css (relevant parts) look?

Comment: Background images do not dictate the size of the container, so you must have other rules that are causing the scroll bar to appear. Post your markup and style sheet, as reduced as possible, to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: This is my html......

<div class="project_area">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="single_project"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

the following is my css.......


.project_area{background:url(img/project_background.jpg);
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
display:block;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

Answer (score -1):

[Perfect Background image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) (from **[css-trick.com](http://css-tricks.com/)**)

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Example :**

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I tried as your code.But the problem still not away @Zeratops

Comment: Try to add `padding-bottom`. _padding-bottom = 100 * height / width = 100 * 150 / 250 = 75_